# How to use UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

[image: View of my viewController]

Swift language preferred.

I want UIPageViewController to have three viewControllers in it(check image).
I do not know how to implement the three viewControllers into the UIPageViewController correctly, before i posted this question i have looked around on the forum for similar questions but i did not find any.

On the white viewController i have connected other viewControllers onto it, i basically just want the same swipe navigation like "Youtube" and "SnapChat".

I am very new to Xcode and if possible a bit a detailed explanation so i will understand the concept of it.(I already read the about UIPageViewController on Apple´s website.)

Swift language preferred.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways you can use it. This is how i prefer to do it.

```
class PagingController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    let pageController:UIPageViewController

    //Initializing PageController
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Assingning the protocol inplemetation
        pageController.dataSource = self
        //Adding the view
        if let initialViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(0) {
            pageController.setViewControllers([initialViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated:false, completion: nil)
            addChildViewController(pageController)
            view .addSubview(self.pageController.view)
            pageController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
    }


    //Adding the next view controller
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentDay = ((viewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! DietDayTableViewController).currentDay
        let nextDay = (currentDay + 1) % 7

        return viewControllerAtIndex(nextDay)
    }


    //Adding the previous view controller
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentDay = ((viewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! DietDayTableViewController).currentDay

        let previousDay = ((currentDay - 1) + 7) % 7

        return viewControllerAtIndex(previousDay)
    }


    //A function witch gives me the right view controller for each page
    func viewControllerAtIndex(index:Int) -> UINavigationController?{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DietDayTableViewController") as? DietDayTableViewController {
            vc.currentDay = index
            return UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

I add comments for help. This pageController is for the days of the week. Each page is a day and i am using the same viewController for each page. The concept of pageviewcontroller is that you have asign the previous view controller and the next of the current one.

Comment: thanks, i have a question about you doing this:  class PagingController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource { }. Where do i put this line of code? is it in the first view controller? if so will it not conflict with my class already in that viewcontroller.swift file?

Comment: Where did you get `DietDayTableViewController ` from?